# Gradle will not build an executable when I include a header

Tags: java, c++, gradle, build, executable

I am doing experiments with gradle as a native binary build tool, and I am getting the weirdest issue that I can't seem to figure out. If I remove the include directory from gradle.build, i get an exe just fine (commenting out the method call of course), but when I include the header directory, it says it builds fine with no issues, but I don't have an executable anymore. I've tried a few different setups, but everyone seems to say that this should work. External libraries load fine. It acts as if it just doesn't want to compile with the include.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Chpt_1.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

    Chpt_1.count();
    return 0;
}
```

Chat_1.h

```
#ifndef CHPT_1_H
#define CHPT_1_H

#include <iostream>

int count() {
    std::cout << "Count!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

#endif
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'cpp'

model {
    components {
        main(NativeExecutableSpec) {
            sources {
                cpp {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/main/cpp"
                        include "src/main/headers"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Directory structure

```
Shards

build.gradle
[other misc files]
-src
--main
---cpp
----main.cpp
---headers
----Chpt_1.h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite late answer, but maybe it helps other people.

Your `gradle.build` should specify the source files in the "sources" section. I could not find a way to define a separate "include" directory. But the way you tried doesn't do it the way it is intended to be.
Change `sources` to

```
sources {
    cpp {
        source {
            srcDir "src/main/cpp"
            include "**/*.cpp"
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle will only compile the cpp files in `src/main/cpp`.

All the include files must be imported relatively to the source directory. For instance

```
#include "../includes/Chpt_1.h"
```

or you copy include files to the same directory.

Comment: I think I eventually found a way to make it work, but CMake does it better. Much better. I might try gradle in the future, but they're very obscure about proper usage. Either way, thanks for an answer.